# Xamarin IOS app crashes only after putting on itunesconnect and physical device

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, crash

I have an app that is using the [Portable razor library](https://github.com/xamarin/PortableRazor) to build out a few webviews in Xamarin. It works fine in the simulator and when debugging on a physical device, but as soon as I deploy to itunesconnect and install via testflight, it crashes immediately on startup. I've updated to the most recent versions of Xcode and Visual studio, but no luck. Below is the crash log, but it provides no clues that I can see. Any ideas on what is going on?

```html
Date/Time:           2018-02-28 07:22:49.5734 -0600
Launch Time:         2018-02-28 07:22:49.3343 -0600
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.6 (15D100)
Baseband Version:    3.42.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001841942e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001842a92f8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396 (pthread.c:1484)
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000184103060 __abort + 152 (abort.c:128)
3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000184102fc8 abort + 152 (abort.c:99)
4   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000104dc3e40 xamarin_get_block_descriptor + 4496
5   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000104dbedfc 0x104a90000 + 3337724
6   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000104c9e684 0x104a90000 + 2156164
7   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000104ceaa34 0x104a90000 + 2468404
8   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000104cea5a4 0x104a90000 + 2467236
9   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000104dc3744 xamarin_get_block_descriptor + 2708
10  GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000104dc9a20 xamarin_get_block_descriptor + 28016
11  GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000104a98188 0x104a90000 + 33160
12  libdyld.dylib                  0x000000018406456c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001842a6b68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001842a6b68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001841940f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001842aace4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640 (pthread_cond.c:579)
2   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000104da4e50 0x104a90000 + 3231312
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001842a82b4 _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001842a8180 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001842a6b74 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000031   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x00000001b7d1a004
   x12: 0x00000001b7d1a004  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0xfffffff013edd260  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b59edb80  x21: 0x0000000104ed1000  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b59edc60
   x24: 0x0000000105564e2a  x25: 0x0000000104de16e1  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000104e654f0
   x28: 0x0000000104e654d0   fp: 0x000000016b36e9a0   lr: 0x00000001842a92f8
    sp: 0x000000016b36e970   pc: 0x00000001841942e8 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

EDIT: I think this is a better crash log that I recently got. Points to the `print_callback` function as causing the crash, which I can't find in my project anywhere.

```html
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000184bd42e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000184ce92f8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396 (pthread.c:1484)
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000184b43060 __abort + 152 (abort.c:128)
3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000184b42fc8 abort + 152 (abort.c:99)
4   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000100e460d4 print_callback(char const*, int) + 3383508 (runtime.m:1211)
5   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000100e40ff0 monoeg_g_log + 3362800 (goutput.c:125)
6   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000100d1ad58 load_aot_module + 2157912 (aot-runtime.c:2071)
7   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000100d67474 mono_assembly_load_from_predicate + 2471028 (assembly.c:2316)
8   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000100d66fdc mono_assembly_open_predicate + 2469852 (assembly.c:1973)
9   GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000100e459d8 xamarin_open_and_register + 3381720 (runtime.m:943)
10  GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000100e4bcb4 xamarin_main + 3407028 (monotouch-main.m:434)
11  GlenroyCalculatorAppiOS        0x0000000100b12ddc main + 28124 (main.m:49)
12  libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000184aa456c start + 4
```

Comment: Did you try deploying the application directly to your phone using a Release configuration and then watching the output using [XCode](https://docs.buddybuild.com/troubleshooting/getting_device_logs_from_xcode.html) or [LemonJar](http://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/)? If that doesn't work, you can try symbolicating your iOS log as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SECTION2).

Comment: @Demitrian I'll try those few things. I believe I tried running it with the release config before, but I've been coming back to this project off and on for months, so I'm not certain

Comment: Let me know how it went, @tetz2442.

Comment: @Demitrian I've updated my question with a symbolicated log. I just tested a release build on my phone again with no issues

Comment: Interesting. Are you certain that the release configuration you are using is identical to the one which you use for uploading to TestFlight? Since you are using a third party library, could linking perhaps be the issue? Also, do you have a link to the library you refer to (i.e. "Razor")?

Comment: @tetz2442 Such issues might be mostly due to some permissions. Can you verify if you are using some sort of permissions and include them in your plist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission problem, but didn't show up until xcode 9.3 when I used that to build my app for release. If you don't specify certain Info.plist keys, your app will crash as soon as it requests them. This was especially confusing because I wasn't using any of the permissions it was telling me I was. Hope this helps someone else.

[image]